# Simple node binding with polymer

Tags: javascript, html, data-binding, polymer

I'm new to polymer and wanted to get started with something simple. I'm not too familiar with all the terminology yet so it's hard for me to google the right thing.

Anyway, I've found that I can access the textContent of the text within the 'shallow dom'? fairly easily:

```
<!-- This is part of my-element element -->
<template>
  {{textContent}} <!-- Outputs all the text -->
  {{foo.textContent}} <!-- Doesn't output anything as I'd hoped it would.. -->
  {{test.textContent}} <!-- Doesn't output anything as I'd hoped it would.. -->
</template>
```

However, I can't seem to access specific text content of child elements within my main page:

```
<!-- This is part of index.html -->
<my-element>
   <test>Some text here</test>
   <foo>Something else</foo>
</my-element>
```

So is there a way of getting at the textContent of  and  explicitly? I'm aware this is probably fairly easy with JS, but I have a feeling there's probably an in-built polymer way of doing this, much like just accessing {{textContent}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so it was fairly simple. Rather than using the moustache syntax I could just do the following in my template:

```
Foo is: <content select="foo"></content><br>
Test is: <content select="test"></content><br>
```

this outputs:

```
Foo is Some text here
Test is: Something else
```